# Submitting two forms in succession with rvest

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am attempting to use rvest to extract a csv file from this webpage: http://www.voterfind.com/athensoh/vtrreport.aspx

I'm wondering about how to use rvest to submit two forms in succession. Clicking the "Start Processing" button on the first form leads to a second form with the "Download My File" button.

Here's the code that I have so far, which resulted in a list instead of the data set that the csv file contains.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)`

`url <- "http://www.voterfind.com/athensoh/vtrreport.aspx"
pgsession <- html_session(url)
pgform <- html_form(pgsession)[[1]]
filled_form <- set_values(pgform, `grp_output` = TRUE)
athens <- submit_form(pgsession, filled_form)
```

Below is a snippet of the list. The above `submit_form` led me to this list that captures some elements of a webpage, instead of the desired data set contained in the csv file. This seems to indicate that I was unable to submit two forms in succession, from the page with the "Start Processing" button to the page with the "Download My File" button.

```
List of 7
 $ handle  :List of 2
  ..$ handle:Class 'curl_handle' <externalptr> 
  ..$ url   : chr "http://www.voterfind.com/athensoh/vtrreport.aspx"
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "handle"
 $ config  :List of 7
  ..$ method    : NULL
  ..$ url       : NULL
  ..$ headers   : NULL
  ..$ fields    : NULL
  ..$ options   :List of 1
  .. ..$ autoreferer: int 1
  ..$ auth_token: NULL
  ..$ output    : NULL
  ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "request"
 $ url     : chr "http://www.voterfind.com/athensoh/underprocess.aspx"
 $ back    : chr(0) 
 $ forward : chr(0) 
 $ response:List of 10
  ..$ url        : chr "http://www.voterfind.com/athensoh/underprocess.aspx"
  ..$ status_code: int 200
```

Does anyone know how I can get to the csv file?

Comment: can you add a bit more information about what your current result is and what your goal is?

Comment: Hi @JonathanHill, I've added more information in the post. I hope that answers your question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is a page in the middle that says you may have a few minutes, and that is what gets captured in the response before the final page with the "Download My File" button. I think you may need to try using Selenium or something similar to simulate the browser.